Oracle - Full table scan even I have index for the query
Consider:

SELECT  *
FROM
             ( SELECT
    key1,
    JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.jsonElement2'),
    JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.date1') ,
    JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.date2'),
    json_col1,
    created
FROM
    table_name
WHERE NOT JSON_EXISTS ( "json_col1" FORMAT JSON, '$?( (@.jsonElement1 in ("NAME")) )'
                 
)
AND JSON_EXISTS ( "json_col1" FORMAT JSON, '$?( (@.jsonElement2 in ("SAMPLE"))
&& (@.jsonElement3 in ("CORE")) )' )
AND JSON_EXISTS ( "json_col2" FORMAT JSON, '$?(  (
(@.json_element5 == "" || (!exists(@.json_element6))) ))'
)
AND CAST((JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.id')) AS INTEGER) > 1
ORDER BY
    CAST((JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.id')) AS INTEGER)
)
WHERE rownum <= 10

My index is:
CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."INDEX_ONE" ON "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME" 
(
JSON_VALUE("json_col1" FORMAT JSON , '$.jsonElement1' RETURNING VARCHAR2(300) ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY), 
JSON_VALUE("json_col1" FORMAT JSON , '$.jsonElement2' RETURNING VARCHAR2(300) ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY), 
JSON_VALUE("json_col1" FORMAT JSON , '$.jsonElement3' RETURNING VARCHAR2(300) ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY),
JSON_VALUE("json_col2" FORMAT JSON , '$.json_element5' RETURNING VARCHAR2(300) ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY), 
JSON_VALUE("json_col2" FORMAT JSON , '$.json_element6' RETURNING VARCHAR2(300) ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY),
JSON_VALUE("json_col1" FORMAT JSON , '$.id' RETURNING VARCHAR2(300) ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) 

Mentioned, the query & index that I am using.
Why was my created index not picked by Oracle Database when I checked for the explain plan?

Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN

@NickW Updated with the screenshot

Why do you believe using an index would be faster?  It is not obvious that any of the predicates in your query are particularly selective.  If you need to examine a large fraction of the rows in the table, a table scan is more efficient.  If the combination of predicates is actually selective enough to make using an index worthwhile, it seems unlikely that choosing a leading column where you are doing a not json_exists is a wise choice.

Please review Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? (e.g., "Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.") and do the right thing (it covers program input as well). Thanks in advance.

You can try two things add CAST to the index column of ID and use JSON_VALUE based on which the index is defined
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT key1,
                 JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.jsonElement2') AS jsonElement2_val,
                 JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.date1') AS date1_val,
                 JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.date2') AS date2_val,
                 json_col1,
                 created
            FROM table_name
           WHERE CAST((JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.id')) AS INTEGER) > 1
             AND JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.jsonElement1') <> 'NAME'
             AND JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.jsonElement2') = 'SAMPLE'
             AND JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.jsonElement3') = 'CORE'
             AND (JSON_VALUE(json_col2, '$.json_element5') is null OR
                  JSON_VALUE(json_col2, '$.json_element6') is null
           ORDER BY CAST((JSON_VALUE(json_col1, '$.id')) AS INTEGER))
   WHERE rownum <= 10;

